# How to read response error from youtube v3

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

I make a call to get my response and info , and then print it to view all is ok.

```
$data = file_get_contents( [CALL TO API]  );
$data = json_decode($data, true);
print("<pre>".print_r($data,true)."</pre>");
```

If the call is good, I will get my result no problem.
but while testing, I need to know when it fails and why.

In the online test demo area, I will get this if it fail's.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.subscription",
    "reason": "subscriptionForbidden",
    "message": "The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The requester is not allowed to access the requested subscriptions."
 }
}
```

But I only get a plank page.
So I then decided to look at my return header with

```
var_dump(headers_list());
var_dump(http_response_code());
```

This gives me

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(23) "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.7" }
int(200)
```

As you see, it is giving me a "200" OK header, but not much else.
So how can I see what the youtube DEMO page shows me?
This would also be helpful later on for error checking when my site is finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = file_get_contents([CALL TO API]);
print_r($data); // Will print the response HTTP body
print_r($http_response_header); // Will print the response HTTP headers
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The " $http_response_header " gives me -- Array ( [0] => HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden [1] => Vary: X-Origin [2] => Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 [3] => Date: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 16:18:25 GMT [4] => Expires: Sun, 05 Mar 2017 16:18:25 GMT [5] => Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 [6] => X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff [7] => X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN [8] => X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block [9] => Server: GSE [10] => Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34" [11] => Accept-Ranges: none [12] => Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding ) But still no YouTube info retuned

Comment: Well, you're obviously getting a **403 Forbidden** status for some reason. Take a look to *youtube v3* documentation to find out why. Good luck.

Comment: I know the reason for the 403 code. My issue is not been able to get the api response for the error. I am wanting the printable response from the api. But thanks for helping me to read the headers a bit better. P.S. print_r($data) still did nothing as before.